# Получить от пользователя большой файл (20+Гб)

Tags: php, файлы

задача такая, получить от пользователя файл с данными для дальнейшей обработки, файл огромный, может быть больше 20Гб. Как корректно обработать на сервере я знаю, меня больше волнует, как его получить на сервер по уму. Может кто сталкивался с подобным и подскажет разумный способ для получения. Спасибо

Comment: http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/js/html5-ajax-partial-upload/

Comment: File Transfer Protocol

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо, то, что нужно)